# R - Cleaning numbers that arent correctly entered

Tags: r, data-cleaning

**EDIT: I have modified the question a little. I apolozise for not understanding the full nature of the problem in the beginning.**

Im working on cleaning data that is gathered from several people. While most people enter data in the correct format, i have found that some of them are 'lazy entries'

Below is my input dataset:

```
|  ID                       | Name    | Age  |
|--------------------------------------------|
|  123456/7/56617181/82     | ABC     | 23   |
|  12134/135                | CDE     | 24   |
```

And here is what I want:

```
|  ID                               | Name    | Age  |
|----------------------------------------------------|
|  123456/123457/56617181/56617182  | ABC     | 23   |
|  12134/12135                      | CDE     | 24   |
```

*Once I have this, all i need to do is to generate an individual row for every ID. I've already figured this bit out. Nonetheless, this is what I will finally have:*

```
|  ID         | Name    | Age  |
|------------------------------|
|  123456     | ABC     | 23   |
|  123457     | ABC     | 23   |
|  56617181   | ABC     | 23   |
|  56617182   | ABC     | 23   |
|  12134      | CDE     | 24   |
|  12135      | CDE     | 24   |
```

Any idea on how one could go about doing this in R? I know this should be do able, I don't know where to look for an answer.

Comment: Perhaps `df$ID <- sapply(strsplit(df$ID, '/'), function(x) {x[2] <- paste0(substr(x[1], 1, max(nchar(x))-min(nchar(x))), x[2]);paste(x, collapse="/")})`

Comment: thanks akrun for such a fast reply, however i realized the problem is not so simple after i posted the question. there are other issues along with this.

Comment: Without knowing the other issues, it is difficult for others to provide solution.

Comment: Yes, I have made changes to the question, I hope thats alright.

Answer (score 2):

We could use `cSplit` from `library(splitstackshape)` to split the 'ID' column at `/`, by specifying the `direction='long'`, we reshape the data from 'wide' to 'long' format.  The output is a `data.table`, so we can use standard data.table techniques.  We group by 'Name', and create another grouping variable ('ind') so that adjacent 2 elements fall into one group.  In the next step, we group by 'Name' and 'ind', get the `nchar` of 'ID', `substr` the 1st element based on the `max` and `min` of `nchar`, `paste` it with the 2nd element (This is based on the example provided. If the values with less `nchar` appears first, we may have to use the `which.max` to select the element to be used in the `substr` ), concatenate (`c`) the first element, convert to `numeric` to create the 'ID' column.

```
library(splitstackshape)
library(data.table)
cSplit(df1, 'ID', '/', 'long')[, ind:=gl(.N, 2, .N) , by = Name
       ][, {i1 <- nchar(ID)
            list(ID=as.numeric(c(ID[1],
              paste0(substr(ID[1],1, max(i1)-min(i1)), ID[2]))),
             Age=Age)} , by = .(Name, ind)][, ind:= NULL][]
#  Name       ID Age
#1:  ABC   123456  23
#2:  ABC   123457  23
#3:  ABC 56617181  23
#4:  ABC 56617182  23
#5:  CDE    12134  24
#6:  CDE    12135  24
```

As I mentioned above, if the ID values with shorter substring occurs first, we may have to use `which.max/which.min` to select the 'ID'

```
cSplit(df1, 'ID', '/', 'long')[, ind:=gl(.N, 2, .N) ,Name
       ][,{i1 <- nchar(ID)
          i2 <- which.max(i1)
          i3 <- which.min(i1)
          list(ID=c(ID[i2],paste0(substr(ID[i2], 1, max(i1)-min(i1)), 
                  ID[i3])), Age=Age)} ,
                               by = .(Name, ind)]
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(ID = c("123456/7/56617181/82", "12134/135"),
 Name = c("ABC", 
"CDE"), Age = 23:24), .Names = c("ID", "Name", "Age"), 
class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -2L))
```

Comment: What happens to the code if there are groups of three numbers instead of two? Or if there are multiple groups of varying length? For example, there could be 151314/13/19/177161/62

Comment: @A.Koirala As I mentioned earlier, you have to show an example that mimics that original dataset.  The code was based on the example you showed.